# How can I get wp post link from mysql database?

Tags: wordpress

I'm building an script that requires to get my posts url but it is in another host, so I can just get that by connecting to database (I cannot get from wp functions). How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: You have to send a GET request to get the posts from that host if it allows and sends some post that way, then grab the post->guid. Also check [WP Rest](http://v2.wp-api.org/) plugin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can get using mysql query to get post_status ,post_name and id after you can get your site url and concatenate the post name with  site url...